# ¿Como retornar una consulta de un metodo a otro metodos en Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, array

Estoy necesitando pasar una consulta que esta en un metodo a otro metodo que la reciba, probablemente pienses en esto:

```
public function query($document)
{
    $query = Tabla::select('*')->where('codemp', '=', $document)->first();
    return $query
}

public function recibe()
{
    $consulta = $this->query();
    dd($consulta);
}
```

Lo anterior es un ejemplo, no es mi consulta, la consulta que tengo es muuy extensa y no merece la pena mostrarla para la solucion que necesito. Bueno, el detalle aqui es que como la consulta anterior no funciona, porque el metodo `first()` de **laravel** convierte la consulta en un objeto, y el `return` intenta retornar un `string` pues aloja un **error** referente a que no se puede retornar un objeto, entonces intente con convertir la consulta a un **JSON** y retornarla a el otro metodo como json pero como un json no puedo recorrerla para la funcion que ya está definida para enviar datos a un **PDF**.

En conclusión lo que necesito es retornar esa consulta con `first()` para posteriormente recorrer cada campo extraido como:

```
$query->id;
```

Agradezco una ayuda de antemano...

Answer (score 0):

No creo que el error que mencionas sea por tratar de devolver un *objecto* y mucho menos que tu función intente devolver un *string* por si sola.

A simple vista lo que parece es que la función **query($document)** necesita un argumento llamado **$document** para funcionar, entonces cuando la quieres utilizar estas obviando este parametro

```
public function recibe()
{
   //$consulta = $this->query();
   $document = "algun valor de cualquier tipo";
   $consulta = $this->query($document); //debería quedar así
   dd($consulta);
}
```

Revisalo y espero te sea de ayuda